# (PHP) (SQL) What is wrong with the syntax of INSERT INTO?

Tags: php, sql, insert

```
[1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1] in EXECUTE("INSERT INTO mailer_recipients (status,send_result_id) VALUES (,)")

public function saveData($status, $resultId)
{
    global $dbwriter;

    // Update send result, send result ID, status
    $sql = 'UPDATE ' . $this->recipientDbTable . ' SET ' . $this->recipientDbColumn['status'] . "='$status' WHERE " . $this->recipientDbColumn['id'] . '=' . $this->getId();
    $sql = 'UPDATE ' . $this->recipientDbTable . ' SET ' . $this->recipientDbColumn['result_id'] . "='$resultId' WHERE " . $this->recipientDbColumn['id'] . '=' . $this->getId();

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->recipientDbTable;
    $sql .= ' (' . $this->recipientDbColumn['status'] . ',' . $this->recipientDbColumn['result_id'] . ')';
    $sql .= ' VALUES ' . '(' . $status . ',' . $resultId . ')';

    $result = $dbwriter->execute($sql);

}
```

The UPDATE's are fine. Can't tell what the problem is.

Comment: Don't downvote mayyyyyyyyLMAO

Comment: Note that you don't appear to be executing your `UPDATE` statements at all, just building their SQL and then immediately overwriting it.

Comment: Lol whoops haha, thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your error message. Your SQL ends with `VALUES (,)`, which is not valid syntax. Apparently, `$status` and `$resultId` are empty (`''`, `null`, or other values that evaluate to empty strings).

Comment: Whoops haha. Thanks will accept this answer when it lets me.